# Copying address of active directory in VIFM

Tags: vifm

Is there a way to yank the address of the active directory within vifm?

Comment: What research have you done thus far? What has that shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following command in `vifm`'s command prompt:

```
:!echo %d %S
```

Where the following is occurring:

- `!echo` - calls the shell's echo command
- `%d` - (%d %"d) - full path to current directory. (vifm-%d)
- `%S` - show command output in the status bar. (vifm-%S)

This results in the current directory being displayed:

[image: ss#1]

#### References

- [Vimfm documentation](http://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

The key combination `yd` will yank the current directory path into the clipboard. This keyboard mapping is defined in the default `.vimrc` file that is included in the vifm package. You need to have `xclip` installed, otherwise the predifined mapping won't work.